# Store string into array in c

Tags: c, arrays

As i know, i can create an array with item inside such as:

```
char *test1[3]= {"arrtest","ao", "123"};
```

but how can i store my input into array like code above because i only can code it as

```
input[10];
scanf("%s",&input) or gets(input);
```

and it store each char into each space.

How can i store the input **"HELLO"** such that it stores into input[0] but now

H to input[0],E to input[1], and so on.

Comment: you don't need `&` before `input` in `scanf("%s", input)`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need a 2 dimensional character array to have an array of strings:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char strings[3][256];
    scanf("%s %s %s", strings[0], strings[1], strings[2]);
    printf("%s\n%s\n%s\n", strings[0], strings[1], strings[2]);
}
```

Comment: what does `256` means in `strings` array?

Comment: @alex that is the length of each string. So there is an array of 3 strings, and each string has space for 256 characters (really only 255 characters, because there is always a terminating null character (`\0`) at the end of a string)

Answer (score 2):

Use a 2-dimensional array `char input[3][10];`
or
an array of `char` pointers (like `char *input[3];`) which should be allocated memory dynamically before any value is saved at those locations.

First Case, take input values as `scanf("%s", input[0]);`, similarly for `input[1]` and `input[2]`. Remember you can store a string of max size `10` (including `'\0'` character) in each `input[i]`.

In second case, get input the same way as above, but allocate memory to each pointer `input[i]` using `malloc` before. Here you have flexibility of size for each string.

Answer (score 0):

Did not really understand what you need. But here is what I guessed.

```
char *a[5];//array of five pointers

for(i=0;i<5;i++)// iterate the number of pointer times in the array
{
char input[10];// a local array variable
a[i]=malloc(10*sizeof(char)); //allocate memory for each pointer in the array here
scanf("%s",input);//take the input from stdin
strcpy(a[i],input);//store the value in one of the pointer in the pointer array
}
```

Comment: example if i input "HELLO"

when i printf("%s", input);
my output should HELLO but not H.

Answer (score 0):

try below code:

```
char *input[10];
input[0]=(char*)malloc(25);//mention  the size you need..
scanf("%s",input[0]);
printf("%s",input[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int main()
{

int n,j;
cin>>n;
char a[100][100];
for(int i=1;i<=n;i++){
    j=1;
    while(a[i][j]!=EOF){
        a[i][j]=getchar();
        j++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

This code inspired me on how to get my user input strings into an array. I'm new to C and to this board, my apologies if I'm not following some rules on how to post a comment. I'm trying to figure things out.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()

{

char strings[3][256];

scanf("%s %s %s", strings[0], strings[1], strings[2]);

printf("%s\n%s\n%s\n", strings[0], strings[1], strings[2]);

}
```