# C char array storing a variable

Tags: c, arrays

I would like to store 2 variables into char array, and print our the first one as shown below.

```
const char *a[2];
            a[0] = getCapital(bufferStore); //"Australia"
            a[1] = getCurrencyCode(bufferStore); "9876.00"

            printf("%s", a[0]);
```

However, I did not get any output. The code of getCapital and getCurrencyCode should be redundant here. The main thing I want to find out is how I can print out "Australia". I'm new to C language and pointers are really hard to understand, and my assignment is due in 2 hours. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21376645/store-string-into-array-in-c

Comment: Are you *sure* the code of the functions is redundant? It seems to be very important to your problem.

Comment: Also, have you tried debugging your application? Have you tried adding a newline at the end of the string to flush it out?

Comment: Thank you Joachim Pileborg! I added a newline and it just works. I can't believe this.

Comment: If your program did a normal exit right after that `printf` then the newline would not have been necessary to make the string visible (although it would display without a newline of course). The newline cased the internal output buffer to "flush", as would a normal program exit/return. Context is everything.

Comment: `a` is not a "char array"! It is an array of **pointers** to `char`.Provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file `stdout`, which is what `printf` writes to, is by default *line buffered*. That means everything you write to it is buffered, i.e. stored in memory, and is flushed (and actually printed) when you print a newline.

Comment: As @lurker mentions in the comments to the OP, the change in behavior by adding `'\n'` or `fflush(stdout)` indicates abnormal termination of the program, hinting at bigger problems.

Comment: @EOF Maybe, but without a MCVE it's really impossible to tell.